# Saving multiple registered variables to a file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

How could I save multiple registered variables to a file using Ansible?

Goal:
I would like to gather information from various commands and save the result

My Playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Find the process
  shell: ps auxk +rss | tail
  register: process_name

- name: Check system activity
  shell: sar -W
  register: sar_output

- name: Run smem
  command: smem -s swap
  when:
    - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat"
    - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "7"
  register: smem_usage
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Save content to a file
  local_action: copy content="{{ item }}" dest="/tmp/swap_info.txt"
  with_items:
    - "{{ process_name }}"
    - "{{ sar_output }}"
    - "{{ smem_usage }}"
```

But the /tmp/swap_info.txt contains only the last registered variable i.e - smem_usage info.

Comment: you can create a list of all the vars you want to save with a looped `set_fact` task, then run the `copy` module

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)

```
- template:
    src: swap_info.txt.j2
    dest: /tmp/swap_info.txt
```

.

```
# cat swap_info.txt.j2
{{ process_name }}
{{ sar_output }}
{{ smem_usage }}
```

Comment: Template is a great option , but unfortunately I need to attach the file that gets created  and use it in the mail module and template is not working for attachments with the mail module.

Answer (score 1):

Lineinfile module can do it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Test
    lineinfile:
      path: ./test.txt
      line: "Hello {{ item }}"
      create: true
    with_items:
      - "Test 1"
      - "Test 2"
      - "Test 3"
```